# vCenter Static IP registration in Win 2008r2 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to figure out how to register static IP of my vCenter Server Version 6.5 in DNS of Windows 2008 R2. To be clear, I am not talking about FQDN. Please take a look at both the sentences from the Installation Manual of vCenter 6.5.

> Before you deploy the vCenter Server Appliance or Platform Services
>   Controller appliance with a static IP address, you must verify that
>   this IP address has a valid internal domain name system (DNS)
>   registration.
>
> If you plan to use an FQDN for the appliance system name, you must
>   verify that the FQDN is resolvable by a DNS server.

Thanks.

Manish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an A record for the vCenter's name in your AD DNS. That's all.
Make sure a reverse PTR record is added too.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite. reserve or reverse?